# Importing .xls files into Access 365

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have various .xls files which I am unable to open in Excel because they are too big.
I have been trying to import them into Access 365 but get the error that Access unable to access the information in the file.
I have been reading advice from several forums this morning but the only suggestions are not workable because they require opening the file and saving in .xlsx, which I can't do because as stated above I can't open the file.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you have an Excel file that you can't open in Excel?  You must have used Excel, at some point, to create the file.  The only limit, as I know, is the RAM on the machine you are working with.

Can you try the following script?

```
Sub Import()

        Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
        Dim strTable As String
        Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

        ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
        ' has field names
        blnHasFieldNames = False

        ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
        ' contains the EXCEL files
        strPath = "C:\Documents\"

        ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
        ' the data are to be imported
        strTable = "tablename"

        strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
              strPathFile = strPath & strFile
              DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                    strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

        ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
        ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
        '       Kill strPathFile

              strFile = Dir()
        Loop

End Sub
```

If Access can't handle it, and I find that hard to believe, you can use SQL Server to do the work.

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm

```
Select * into SQLServerTable FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\testing.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

http://www.ashishblog.com/importexport-excel-xlsx-or-xls-file-into-sql-server/

Or...use R for this task.

```
library(xlsx)
file <- system.file("tests", "test_import.xlsx", package = "xlsx")
res <- read.xlsx(file, 1)  # read first sheet
head(res[, 1:6])
```

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-xlsx-package-a-quick-start-guide-to-manipulate-excel-files-in-r

If none of those options work, I would say the Excel file is probably corrupt, and that's a whole different problem.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for all of the above. RAM is the issue it seems as the work laptop just doesn't cope. The files are system downloads from Oracle db so have not been created by a user. But the problem I had using access to handle the files seemed to be related to the fact the files were .xls and access said it couldn't read the data.